# Is the randomized motion of particles produce heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

In the show on factomania from gregg foot I've heard that when sun light comes then some gas particles of air get more energy and velocity and as the average kinetic energy of molecules is Temperature the temperature increases for the same region . Now if thats true empty space should have no heat as it is and earth atmosphere should have. So is this explanation true. Or light carries radiation energy and heat energy separately ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heat is energy transfer from one thing to another due solely to there being a temperature difference between the two. Things do not "contain" heat. The earth's atmosphere does not contain heat. Temperature is a measure of average translational kinetic energy component of a substances internal energy.

The three basic types of heat transfer are conduction, convection, and radiation. The first two require some type of substance to enable the transfer, such as a liquid, solid, or gas. The third (radiation) does not as the transfer is in the form of electromagnetic radiation. No medium is needed for electromagnetic radiation.

Heat transferred from the sun to the earth and its atmosphere is by electromagnetic radiation. This energy transfer occurs through the vacuum of space.

Hope this helps.